# How to select class inside $(this)

Tags: jquery, html

Here's my html code:

```
<div class="main_box_background">
    <div class="main_box_bg_left">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="main_box_background">
    <div class="main_box_bg_left">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="main_box_background">
    <div class="main_box_bg_left">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my jquery code:

```
$('.main_box_background').each(function(){
    var foo = $(this);
    $(this).$( ".main_box_bg_left" ).animate({marginLeft: "-121px"}, 500);
});
```

I just want to select `main_box_bg_left` of `this` indicator.
How can i do that?

Comment: If you're already caching `$(this)`, then use `foo.find(...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you need to use is [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$(this).find( ".main_box_bg_left" ).animate({marginLeft: "-121px"}, 500);
//foo.find( ".main_box_bg_left" ).animate({marginLeft: "-121px"}, 500);
```

Or in this case since the `main_box_bg_left` child of `main_box_background` element you can also use [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

```
$(this).children( ".main_box_bg_left" ).animate({marginLeft: "-121px"}, 500);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/), and there's no need for using `.each()` in this specific case.

```
$('.main_box_background')
    .find( ".main_box_bg_left" ).animate({marginLeft: "-121px"}, 500);
```

A simpler option is selecting the required elements in the first place:

```
$('.main_box_background .main_box_bg_left' )
     .animate({marginLeft: "-121px"}, 500);
```

Comment: `$('.main_box_background .main_box_bg_left')` would be even shorter.

Comment: there are many main_box_background. And, I have used .each() there. I want to select one at once.

Comment: @Prakash The command I've written would work on every element with the class `.main_box_bg_left` in each and every element with the class `.main_box_background`. This is how jQuery works. And ComFreek, thanks

Comment: @Prakash It's a shame you didn't read my comment. Good luck anyway.

Comment: @Itay, I read comment of yours, but, I don't want to reach every element of `.main_box_background`. But, I want to work on `.main_box_bg_left` of `$(this)`.

Comment: You are still iterating `.each()` `.main_box_background` and searching for its `.main_box_bg_left` child...

Answer (score 1):

Your idea was almost correct, just need to change the selector after $(this) to the function find(), like this:

```
$('.main_box_background').each(function(){
    var foo = $(this); //This line is not really necessary
    $(this).find(".main_box_bg_left").animate({marginLeft: "-121px"}, 500);
});
```